# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps') in flutter

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, maps

I'm developing an uber clone, but when I run the application on the web, it doesn't let me see the location on the map and I get this error, it helps!

[image: picture of my mistake]

Here you can also see when the application is executed the result

[image: mistake Web]

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
    import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
    import 'package:rider_app/AllWidgets/Divider.dart';
    import 'package:rider_app/Assistants/assistantsMethods.dart';



    class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget
    {
      static const String idScreen = "mainScreen";
      @override
      _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
    }



    class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen>
    {
      Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMaps = Completer();
      GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;

      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

      Position currentPosition;
      var geoLocator = Geolocator();
      double bottomPaddingOfMap = 0;

      void locatePosition() async
      {
        Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
        currentPosition = position;


        LatLng latLngPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(target: latLngPosition, zoom: 14);
        newGoogleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        String address = await AssistantsMethods.searchCoordinateAddress(position);
        print("Esta es tú dirección :: " + address);
      }

      static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
        zoom: 14.4746,
      );

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Ventana Principal"),
          ),
          drawer: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 255.0,
            child: Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  //Drawer Header
                  Container(
                    height: 165.0,
                    child: DrawerHeader(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Image.asset("images/user_icon.png", height: 65.0,width: 65.0,),
                          SizedBox(width: 16.0,),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text("Nombre del perfil", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontFamily: "Brand-Bold"),),
                              SizedBox(height: 6.0,), 
                              Text("Perfil Visitante"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DividerWidget(),

                  SizedBox(height: 12.0,),

                  //Drawer Body Controller
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.history),
                    title: Text("Historia", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                    title: Text("Perfil de visitante", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.info),
                    title: Text("Sobre", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              GoogleMap(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottomPaddingOfMap),
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller)
                {
                  _controllerGoogleMaps.complete(controller);
                  newGoogleMapController =  controller;

                  setState(() {
                    bottomPaddingOfMap = 300.0;
                  });

                  locatePosition();

                },
              ),

              Positioned(
                top: 45.0,
                left: 22.0,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: ()
                  {
                    scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();

                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          blurRadius: 6.0,
                          spreadRadius: 0.5,
                          offset: Offset(
                            0.7,
                            0.7,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black,),
                      radius: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              Positioned(
                left: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                bottom: 0.0,
                child: Container(
                  height: 300.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(18.0), topRight: Radius.circular(18.0)),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        blurRadius: 16.0,
                        spreadRadius: 0.5,
                        offset: Offset(0.7, 0.7),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 18.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 6.0),
                        Text("Hola,Buen día..", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
                        Text("A dondé quisieras ir?", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: "Brand-Bold"),),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black54,
                                blurRadius: 6.0,
                                spreadRadius: 0.5,
                                offset: Offset(0.7, 0.7),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.blueAccent,),
                                SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                                Text("Buscar una ubicación de entrega")
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 24.0),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.home,color: Colors.grey,),
                            SizedBox(width: 12.0,),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text("Agregar Casa"),
                                SizedBox(height: 4.0,),
                                Text("La dirección de su casa", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500], fontSize: 12.0),),

                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                        DividerWidget(),

                        SizedBox(height: 16.0),

                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.work,color: Colors.grey,),
                            SizedBox(width: 12.0,),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text("Agregar Trabajo"),
                                SizedBox(height: 4.0,),
                                Text("La dirección de su trabajo", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500], fontSize: 12.0),),

                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }


<!-- end snippet -->
```

I hope and you can help giving me a solution or giving me a path so that I can continue because I don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you have [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_web) added to your project? If I remember right, Google Maps on web platform does not work without it.

Comment: Yes, I have that package, and I continue with my mistake

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because you're trying to use [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) on web - which only supports Android and iOS. If you're adding Google Maps plugin on Flutter for web, you need to use [google_maps_flutter_web](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_web)

Comment: I believe this answer is no longer relevant. "This package is endorsed, which means you can simply use google_maps_flutter normally. This package will be automatically included in your app when you do, so you do not need to add it to your pubspec.yaml."

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem. I did the following thing & succeeded.

1. Enable **JavaScript API** from [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=se-project-366807) & install  [Google maps flutter web](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_web).
2. After installation remember to add the following code snippet on the  `web/index.html` path of `flutter project` & enter your own `API key` in the place of `"YOUR_API_KEY"` text of the below code snippet.

```html
<head>

  <!-- // Other stuff -->

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: This one worked for me! Also don't forget to enable the API Key in the Google Cloud Console under "API Keys".

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Will the code have to be re-inserted every time I rebuild the app? What about when I want to build a production build?

Answer (score 1):

Make to modify the `<head>` tag of your `web/index.html` to load the Google Maps JavaScript API, like so:

```
<head>

  <!-- // Other stuff -->

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
</head>
```