# Google map not getting displayed in container

Tags: flutter, dictionary, google-maps, flutter-web

I have an error while rendering the google map does not get displayed. i am trying to display google map in a container. Type error occurred "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')

```
    class GMap extends StatefulWidget {
      const GMap({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<GMap> createState() => _GMapState();
    }
    
    class _GMapState extends State<GMap> {
      late GoogleMapController mapController;
    
      final LatLng _center = const LatLng(26.576771, 87.502151);
    
      void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
        mapController = controller;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 300,
            width: 500,
            child: GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: _center, zoom: 11.0),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you running the app in the browser?

Comment: yeah i am running the app in google chrome

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because you're trying to use google_maps_flutter on web - which only supports Android and iOS. If you're adding Google Maps plugin on Flutter for web, you need to use google_maps_flutter_web

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73123425/11345007

as mentioned in this answer

Comment: @jaminsampang Good to hear!